# Place Widgets at the edge of their parent widget

Tags: flutter

**EDIT**: Added a screenshot of the desired output

---

**Goal:** Placing a group of widgets (`RoundButton`s and `Text` widgets) at the edge of their parent `widget`

---

**Problem:** The widgets that need to move are still close to their nearby widgets

Here is a screenshot showing the problem:

[image: screenshot describing the problem]

Here's the desired output:

[image: Desired output]

---

The following code snippet shows the widgets that I need to move to the end of the parent:
Widgets to be moved: inner Row and its widgets.

```dart
            Row(//parent widget
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(//To be moved to the end of the parent
                          children: <Widget>[
                            RoundIconButton(
                                icon: FontAwesomeIcons.minus, onPressed: () {}),
                            Text('$_counter'),
                            RoundIconButton(
                                icon: FontAwesomeIcons.plus, onPressed: () {}),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Text('10000', style: GoogleFonts.cairo(fontSize: 15)),
                      ],
                    ),
```

---

Here is the current implementation that corresponds to the screenshot above:

```
Container(
          width: deviceWidth,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                child: Column(
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Product',
                      style: GoogleFonts.cairo(
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'subtitle',
                      style: GoogleFonts.cairo(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      ),
                    ),
                    StrikeThroughWidget(
                      child: Text(
                        '5000',
                        style: GoogleFonts.cairo(
                          fontSize: 10,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            RoundIconButton(
                                icon: FontAwesomeIcons.minus, onPressed: () {}),
                            Text('$_counter'),
                            RoundIconButton(
                                icon: FontAwesomeIcons.plus, onPressed: () {}),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Text('10000', style: GoogleFonts.cairo(fontSize: 15)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[350])),
                width: 90,
                height: 90,
                child: FlutterLogo(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

**Already-tried Solutions:**

1. Changing `mainAxisAlignment` of the Row with multiple values but didn't get the desired output
2. Placing the `Row` inside of a `Flex` Widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate the Widgets in multiple layers using `Stack` and use `Position` to place the layers exactly where you want.

```html
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Material(
        child: Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 500,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                      child: Column(
                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Product'),
                          Text('subtitle'),
                          Text('5000'),
                          Text('10000'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[350])),
                      width: 90,
                      height: 90,
                      child: FlutterLogo(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      radius: 20,
                      child: IconButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text('1'),
                    CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      radius: 20,
                      child: IconButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it did help, here's the result: https://snipboard.io/G3IDdY.jpg , I just changed the font in order to maintain the height

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Stack and Positioned:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Material(child: Center(
        child: 
          Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          width: 400,
          height: 100,
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                child: Column(
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Product',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'subtitle',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                        '5000',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 10,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        ),
                      ),


                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[350])),
                width: 90,
                height: 90,
                child: FlutterLogo(),
              ),
            ],
          ),

        Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            RawMaterialButton(
                                child: Text("-"), onPressed: () {}),
                            Text('6'),
                            RawMaterialButton(
                                child: Text("+"), onPressed: () {}),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Text('10000', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                      ],
                    ),),
        ]
       ),),),),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `Spacer`

```
   Row(//parent widget
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(//To be moved to the end of the parent
                      children: <Widget>[
                        RoundIconButton(
                            icon: FontAwesomeIcons.minus, onPressed: () {}),
                        Text('$_counter'),
                        RoundIconButton(
                            icon: FontAwesomeIcons.plus, onPressed: () {}),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Spacer(),//Where I added the spacer
                    Text('10000', style: GoogleFonts.cairo(fontSize: 15)),
                  ],
                ),
```